# Can't type after starting chrome extension debugger

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug my chrome extension, but once I open the debugger, all keyboard extensions are captured by the debugger or the main chrome window, and I can't type in my extension popup. If I don't open the extension debugger, it works fine. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Yes.. Do not activate breakpoints. Breakpoints pause the execution of the program so that you can slowly monitor what happens.

Comment: Sorry, slightly confused - I have no breakpoints, and I still can't type in my textbox with the debugger open.